# Asynchronously await a series of states

Tags: c#, asynchronous, expression, c#-5.0

I am await'ing a sequence of state changes.  My problem is that I want to await a successive state only if the prior was as expected, and this does not work...because it seems the code awaits all states unconditionally.  The Boolean expression in buttonRun_Click works when all goes as expected, but if not, the expression is false, but it seems that the await's are still active.  One symptom is that the form does not exit when closed, because a task is still running.

```
    private void StateChange(Information info)
    {
        // If we are expecting a certain state, and get it, inform our registrant
        this.gState = info;
        this.gStateTask.SafeTrySetResult(this.gStateExpected(this.gState));
    }

    private async Task<bool> ExpectStateAsync(Predicate<Information> expect)
    {
        if (expect(this.gState)) { return true; }
        this.gStateExpected = expect;
        this.gStateTask = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        try
        {
            await this.gStateTask.Task;
            return this.gStateTask.Task.Result;
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private async void buttonRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Command(Request.Run);
        if (await ExpectStateAsync(s => s.Initiated)
            && await ExpectStateAsync(s => s.Scanning)
            && await ExpectStateAsync(s => s.Expect(Status.Attached)))
        {
            ShowError("Job complete");
            // Job completed successfully
        }
    }
```

How can I restructure this code so that I can asynchronously await the first state change then, if I get it, await the second, etc.?  If at any time the state changes to one that was not expected, the Boolean should short-circuit and return false.

Comment: `so that I can asynchronously await the first state change then, if I get it, await the second, etc.? ` - why just don't run them in sync?

Comment: I've only taken a cursory glance at the code, so forgive if this notion is too simpleminded, but I would put the state change logic in a bit more robust structure that, in effect, handles these specific stepwise state changes on its own. I'd think of a class that exposes something like a NextStateReached event that only fires when a normal transition from state n to n+1 takes place. That takes the burden off the listener to ensure a valid stepwise state change occurred...hope this makes some degree of sense...

Comment: Short-circuiting works with `await`, so I think you're wrong when you say, "it seems that the await's are still active".

Comment: `One symptom is that the form does not exit when closed, because a task is still running.` What exactly do you mean by "exit"?

Comment: @TimS. I believe you, and that is why I wrote the code that way, but when I added code to ExpectStateAsync to show when I was waiting, and when things completed, I get more waits than completes.  I can't just await all the states, because it may not go through the expected sequence -- if the first transition fails, the others will never occur.  So what I am still missing?

Comment: @StephenCleary When this code has run, and I close the form in the debugger, I still have to say "Stop Debugging" or it does not exit fully.  In release mode, I have to kill the task.  This does not happen when this code is not run.  (If I Break All to see where, only system code is running.)

Comment: @shipr: Unable to repro. I created a new WinForms app with the following `async void` button click code: `await new TaskCompletionSource<bool>().Task;`. After clicking the button, I am able to exit the app without problems, even though the `await` is never completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the good help I received, I was able to make a generic class I thought worth sharing -- including code for debugging -- that makes it easy to await a series of asynchronous state transitions.  This is tested, working code with no other dependencies except a standard logger with interface ILogger (and C# 4.5 of course).

Using this in my Windows Form made the form extremely responsive -- I was very pleased with how quickly it painted, for example, even while waiting on other tasks.

I made two instances, one a job request:

```
_jobs = new ClassCommandStateProgression<JobState>();

if (await _jobs(CommandExpectedStatesAsync(() => Run(),
    s => s.IsAvailable,
    s => s.IsCleanedUp,
    s => s.IsFinished
    )
{
    Console.Writeline("Job completed successfully!");
}
```

and a request acknowledgment:

```
this.acknowledge = new ClassCommandStateProgression<CommandReplyMessage>();

if (!await this.acknowledge.CommandExpectedStatesAsync(
    () => Command(this, request, parameters),
    s => s.MessageType == request))
{
    ShowError(string.Format("Unexpected reply: {0} instead of {1}", this.State.MessageType, request));
}
```

The event handlers that received the responses called StateTransition() for the two instances.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace States
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a command while asynchronously watching to see that a series of state transitions (of an arbitrary type) will be executed, 
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// A single instance is enough for each type of transition.
    /// <code>
    /// this.Expectations = new ClassCommandStateProgression();
    /// </code>
    /// Invocations should not be interleaved, even though if the state progression does not proceed as expected, the object will be cleaned up.
    /// <code>
    /// if (await this._Expectations.CommandExpectedStatesAsync(command, {state predicates}) { ... }
    /// </code>
    /// It is simple to inform the instance of state changes.
    /// <code>
    /// this._Expectations.StateTransition(state);
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    public class ClassCommandStateProgression<T> where T : class
    {
        // Pair a TaskCompletionSource with a predicate for its completion
        private struct ExpectedTask
        {
            public readonly TaskCompletionSource<bool> _Task;
            public readonly Predicate<T> _Predicate;

            public ExpectedTask(Predicate<T> predicate)
            {
                this._Task = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                this._Predicate = predicate;
            }
        }

        private Queue<ExpectedTask> _Q = new Queue<ExpectedTask>();
        private bool _Result;

        // Debug logging
        private ILogger _Logger;
        private Func<T, string> _IdentifyState;
        private static int _NestingLevel;       // Track waiting

        /// <summary>
        /// No logging by default.
        /// </summary>
        public ClassCommandStateProgression()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// For debugging purposes, identify when the state changes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="logger">The logger to use.</param>
        /// <param name="identifyState">A delegate to describe the state.</param>
        public ClassCommandStateProgression(ILogger logger, Func<T, string> identifyState)
        {
            this._Logger = logger;
            this._IdentifyState = identifyState;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute a command that should cause a series of asynchronous state transitions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="command">The command to execute.</param>
        /// <param name="predicates">A list of predicates describing the expected states.</param>
        /// <returns>True if all state transitions took place as expected.</returns>
        public async Task<bool> CommandExpectedStatesAsync(Action command, params Predicate<T>[] predicates)
        {
            this._Result = true;

            if (null != predicates && predicates.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var predicate in predicates)
                {
                    this._Q.Enqueue(new ExpectedTask(predicate));
                }
            }

            return await AwaitExpectedStatesAsync(command).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute a command that should cause a series of asynchronous state transitions,
        /// perhaps being originally in the first of the states.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="state">The original state.</param>
        /// <param name="command">The command to execute.</param>
        /// <param name="predicates">A list of predicates describing the expected states.</param>
        /// <returns>True if all state transitions took place as expected.</returns>
        public async Task<bool> CommandExpectedStatesAsync(T state, Action command, params Predicate<T>[] predicates)
        {
            this._Result = true;

            if (null != predicates && predicates.Length > 0)
            {
                bool alreadyInState = predicates[0](state);
                foreach (var predicate in predicates)
                {
                    if (alreadyInState)
                    {
                        if (null != this._Logger) { this._Logger.Debug("Already true => {0}", this._IdentifyState(state)); }

                        alreadyInState = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                    this._Q.Enqueue(new ExpectedTask(predicate));
                }
            }

            return await AwaitExpectedStatesAsync(command).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        // Await the queued states.
        private async Task<bool> AwaitExpectedStatesAsync(Action command)
        {
            try
            {
                if (null != this._Logger) { this._Logger.Debug("Waiting for {0} state transitions.", this._Q.Count); }

                // The caller must catch any exceptions thrown by the command.
                command();

                while (this._Result && this._Q.Count > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref gNestingLevel);
                        if (null != this._Logger) { this._Logger.Debug("Awaiting managed thread {0}; at nesting {1}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, gNestingLevel); }

                        var waitFor = this._Q.Peek()._Task;
                        await waitFor.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
                        this._Result = waitFor.Task.Result;

                        Interlocked.Decrement(ref gNestingLevel);
                        if (null != this._Logger) { this._Logger.Debug("Back from await; at nesting {0}.", gNestingLevel); }
                    }
                    catch (TaskCanceledException)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return this._Result;
            }
            finally
            {
                this._Q.Clear();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Transition to the next state.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="state">A state object of the parameterized type <typeparamref name="T"/>.</param>
        public void StateTransition(T state)
        {
            if (this._Q.Count > 0)
            {
                ExpectedTask et = this._Q.Dequeue();
                this._Result = this._Result && et._Predicate(state);
                if (null != this._Logger)
                {
                    if (!this._Result) { this._Logger.Warn("UNEXPECTED! => {0}", this._IdentifyState(state)); }
                    else { this._Logger.Debug("{0}{1}", this._IdentifyState(state), this._Q.Count > 0 ? ", still waiting..." : "."); }
                }
                et._Task.TrySetResult(this._Result);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stop waiting.
        /// </summary>
        public void Cancel()
        {
            if (this._Q.Count > 0) { this._Q.Peek()._Task.TrySetCanceled(); }
        }
    }
}
```